# Java get subList in Python way

Tags: java, arrays

In python, when you select a sublist

```py
a = [1,2,3]
sub_a = a[2:10]
```

It will not blow up but return `[3]`.

In Java, it turns out to be quite different

```java
List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
a.subList(2, 10);
```

An IndexOutOfBoundsException will be thrown.

I am not going to judge the different approaches, but I want to know can Java achieve the same list slicing operation in Python's way?

Comment: Technically, the comparison is not fair. In Python, the arrays are not necessarily true arrays but dynamic arrays. Python hides this fact from you. A fair comparison would probably use `ArrayList` in Java, not actual true arrays. And then it is just about the slicing vs `subList`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Java you have to take care of the slicing yourself:

```
List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
a.subList(2, Math.min(10,a.size()));
```

Comment: Or `a.subList(2)`

Comment: @JoopEggen is there such a variant? I don't see it (at least not in Java 8). And I checked the Javadoc of Java 11 and didn't see it.

Comment: Oh my, mixed it up with `getSubstring`. Sorry